# How to pass "this" pointer to a global function

Tags: c++, constructor, this, visual-c++-2008

```
//This is AsynchronousFunction class header file

typedef int (*functionCall)(int, int);

DWORD __stdcall functionExecuter(LPVOID pContext); // global function

class  AsynchronousFunction
{   

  int param1, param2;
  functionCall fCall;
  HANDLE m_handle;

public:
  AsynchronousFunction(functionCall, int, int);
  ~AsynchronousFunction();
  int result();

protected:
private:
  int returnVal; 

};


It's implementation as follows

AsynchronousFunction::AsynchronousFunction(functionCall fCall, int param1, int       param2):m_handle(CreateEvent( NULL , false , false , NULL))
{
  bool b = QueueUserWorkItem(functionExecuter, this, WT_EXECUTEDEFAULT);

  WaitForSingleObject(m_handle, INFINITE);
  SetEvent(m_handle);
}

AsynchronousFunction::~AsynchronousFunction()
{
  CloseHandle(m_handle);
}

int AsynchronousFunction::result()
{

  return 0;// not implemented yet

}

DWORD __stdcall functionExecuter(LPVOID pContext)
{

  return 0;

}
```

here pContext receives "this" pointer. my attempt is access the param1 and param2
from here and do the work
how can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you can make the `functionExecuter` a friend of `AsynchronousFunction` 
OR
Add a public function in `AsynchronousFunction` which does the required things and call it from `functionExecuter`, something like shown below.

```
DWORD __stdcall functionExecuter(LPVOID pContext)
{
  return (reinterpret_cast<AsyncrhonousFunction*>(pContext))->realFunctionExecuter();
}
```

Comment: I personally prefer to avoid friends unless absolutely necessary, and even then to second guess and see if there's any other way. So I'd prefer the latter approach first. It seems cleaner too.

Comment: @jia103 I agree with you. Second options looks cleaner. I too personally avoid friend functions

Comment: Thank you. I got it. since pContext is a void pointer, it needs to be cast to AsynchronousFunction type.

Comment: I did this.
AsynchronousFunction * obj = reinterpret_cast<AsynchronousFunction*>(pContext);

then via obj, I can access members.

Comment: @YasasCPerera - With `obj` you could only access public members right? Did you just mentioned about accessing public members in the comment above?

Comment: @jia103 Why should friends be avoided? Can you please provide a link.

Comment: @KarthikKalyanasundaram : yes. you are correct. with obj I can access only public members. to access private members, I might need a separate function which invokes from the functionExecuter. it looks going around so I plan to change the design.

sajas : I think friend functions mostly violate the OOP concept. That could be a reason

Answer (score 0):

@sajas Sorry, I don't have an explicit reference other than to refer to Scott Meyers' books or Herb Sutter books; it's just one of those things I picked up along the way. In general, you don't want to break encapsulation by exposing private data if it's not needed, which is exactly what `friend`s do. In this case, if you decide to change the implementation of `AsynchronousFunction` tomorrow and `functionExecuter` was its friend, then it's more likely that you could break `functionExecuter` because it might have relied on the private members; on the other hand, if it was never a friend to begin with, you'd be forced to code `functionExecuter` using `AsynchronousFunction`'s public interface only.